# Why is there no $C>0$ such that $C||f||_q \leq ||f||_p$?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, normed-spaces

> Show that for $1\leq p <q \leq \infty$, there is no $C>0$ such that
>   $C||f||_q \leq ||f||_p$ for all $f\in C([0,1])$.
>
> **Definition:**
>
> Let $a,b\in \mathbb{R}$ with $a<b$ and for $f\in C([a,b])$, $1\leq p
>  <\infty$ let
>
> $$||f||_p=\left(\int_{a}^{b}|f(x)|^p \, dx\right)^{1/p} \text{and }  |
> |f||_\infty := \max\limits_{x\in [a,b]}|f(x)|$$

There's a hint that tells me to compute $||f_n||_p$ and $||f_n||_q$ with  $f_n : [0,1]\to \mathbb{R} , t\mapsto f_n(t)=t^n$ mit $n\in \mathbb{N}$, what exactly do I have to compute? I don't see why this helps...

Comment: Well, you could start by computing $\|f_n\|_p$. What do you get?

Comment: $$||f_n||_p=\left(\int_{a}^{b}|t^n|^p \, dt\right)^{1/p} =\left(\int_{a}^{b}t^{np} \, dt\right)^{1/p} =\left(\frac{t^{np+1}}{np+1}\Bigg |_a^b\right)^{1/p}=\left(\frac{b^{np+1}-a^{np+1}}{np+1}\right)^{1/p}$$ But why?

Comment: But here we are working on the interval $[0,1]$.

Comment: Assume that $C||t^n||_q \le ||t^n||_p$ for all $n$ and let $n \to \infty$. That's what the hint is saying.

Comment: Thanks, Trevor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The hint is saying that you can show that $C$ has to be $0$ (a contradiction) by assuming that $C||t^n||_q \le ||t^n||_p$ for all $n$. For example, if $q = \infty$, we have

$$ C||t^n||_{\infty} = C \le ||t^n||_p = \frac{1}{(1+pn)^{1/p}} \xrightarrow{n\to\infty} 0. $$

Therefore there is no $C > 0$ such that $C||t^n||_{\infty} < ||t^n||_p$ for all $n$.

Now do the same thing but with $q < \infty$.

Comment: Hmm, for $q<\infty$, we have: $C\leq \frac{(1+qn)^{1/q}}{(1+pn)^{1/p}}$. What am I missing?

Comment: @ParabolicAlcoholic It goes to $0$ but it's harder to show. Try raising the fraction to the power of $p$ or $q$ (I'm not sure which works better; maybe both options work) and applying l'Hôpital's rule.

Comment: Okay, I'm trying the squeeze theorem first.

Comment: Doesn't really appear to be working for me...

Comment: $$ \frac{(1+qn)^{1/q}}{(1+pn)^{1/p}} \to \frac{(1+qn)}{(1+pn)^{q/p}} \to \frac{q}{\frac qp (1+pn)^{q/p - 1}} $$ and since $q/p - 1 > 0$, this tends to $0$ as $n \to \infty$. @ParabolicAlcoholic

Comment: Oh my god! As a result of my laziness, I used WolframAlpha to derive $\frac{(1+qn)}{(1+pn)^{q/p}}$ and the result was horrible. What I was missing is how to correctly use L'Hospital's Rule (deriving denominator and numerator seperately)